# List has no rows for assignment even after Insert

Tags: apex

I have inserted a contact and tried querying in next line, but i am getting no record.

```
Contact con=new Contact(lastName='Pikachu');
insert con;
System.debug(con.id); //This is printing the contact id which is real i checked via viewing in detail page
con=[Select id,name,lastName,someFormulaField__C from contact where id=:con.id];
//Some code
```

Am getting List has no rows for assignment exception all of a sudden, this code used to work without any hassle just few hours back.

I tried querying the same id in workbench ,still got no records, but when i try after a minute or two i get record. My instance is **Cs31**, is something wrong with salesforce?

Anyone faced something similar problem?

Comment: You tried this in anonymous code in dev console?

Comment: According to this there is no issue with your instance:[http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances)

Comment: Yes i tried in anon block and we got the same issue

Comment: I encounter the same issue in a full sandbox after it was upgraded to Summer 16. When I add ALL ROWS to the query, it will find the record, but the isDeleted flag indicates false. When I add certain fields to the SELECT section of the query, it does find the record.

Comment: Let me ask something... As you mentioned in the code, Are you querying that Con.id in the same executing Class or Trigger...?

Comment: Looks like when you inserting contact after that contact trigger fired and in that trigger you are getting this error. I suggest deactivate the trigger and then runt this code if you get this error means issue in your trigger. then try to solve issue trigger issue

Comment: Ratan I tried deactivating the trigger, still same issue... tried on another org its working fine.

@svenf after adding order by created date or ALL ROWS one could find the record, But i will have huge code change to do as most of my classes has this old approch.

I think its salesforce issue, cause of recent update rollout, hope they patch it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Salesforce and raised a case for the same. Its a salesforce bug that came with Summer 16 release. The objects that have Skinny tables enabled are causing this issue. A temporary fix provided is to disable the Skinny table. 
More info can be found here.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IXfzQAG

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code in Summer'16 upgraded Sandbox and working fine.

If you still have some issues, please contact Salesforce support or log a case so that they can check there internal logs to verify if there is any known issue or bug.